# prevent initial delay in ajax autoreload

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am using ajax autoreload to load posts in a div

```
function start(){
    refreshcon = setInterval(function(){
        $('#postcontainer').load('new/posts.php', function(){  });
    }, 5000);
}
```

This is working fine. The problem is, when the page is loaded the first time or a link that reloads the whole page is clicked: the posts delay for 5 seconds. How do I make the page initially load without waiting for the five seconds. or what function can I call that loads the posts immediately maybe called by body onload. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jquery, then you can run your loader when page loaded, and then call to work your function with auto reload new posts. Simple code can be like below

```
  function start(){
    refreshcon = setInterval(function(){
        $('#postcontainer').load('new/posts.php', function(){  });
    }, 5000);
  }

  $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#postcontainer').load('new/posts.php', function(){  });
       start();
    });
```

You load your post when page loaded, and then every 5 seconds after

Comment: @jonah, you are welcome), also you can approve my comment as an answer to your question

Comment: I would have voted you up but I don't have enough reputations. I joint stack overflow less than a week ago. Thanks though @Dnister Lark